Angular compiler included both in the main and polyfills chunk - how can I fix that
Angular compiler included both in the main and polyfills chunk - how can I fix that? or where do I start looking for it?
I'm using Angular 18 - on an app that started in angular 5 and was upgraded multiple times - the last time from 13 to 18

Here's my angular json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "ba4eae7a-6f3a-4bca-af89-b7b2859cf746"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hug-moms": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hagai",
            "index": "src/index_dev.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "externalDependencies": [
              "jsonwebtoken",
              "password-hash",
              "nodemailer",
              "fs",
              "aws-sdk"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "aot": false,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "statsJson": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "aot": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "statsJson": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "statsJson": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "hug-moms:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "hug-moms:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Is this the dev build or the prod build?

@kvetis it is the prod build - i bypassed it with aot, but still

Actually AOT has benefits for you unless you really need JIT.  But is seems weird that its included twice in the prod build with optimization: true.
